# Populating object properties from DataSet using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset, datarelation

Here is my current relationship

```
DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("EventCategoryRelation", eventsTable.Columns["event_id"], eventCategoriesTable.Columns["event_id"]);
ds.Tables.Add(eventsTable);
ds.Tables.Add(eventCategoriesTable);
ds.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Here is a quick look through the tables

**EventsTable**

```
event_id | event_description

1 || "First Event"
```

**EventCategoriesTable**

```
event_category_id || event_id || category_id

1 || 1 || 1

2 || 1 || 2
```

Relationship is **many-to-many** (one event is to many categories)

Here is how I populate my DTO's using a foreach loop

```
foreach (DataRow row in eventsTable.Rows)
{
    Event events = new Events();

    events.Description = row["event_description"].ToString();

    DataRow[] aDr = row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation");
    foreach (DataRow dr in aDr)
    {
        Categories category = new Categories();
        category.CategoryID = Int64.Parse(dr["category_id"].ToString());

        events.CategoryList.Add(category);
    }
}
```

I have more fields on my actual code. I want to replace the foreach loop with a LINQ query. Is that possible?

Comment: actually that relationship is many-to-many. One event can have multiple categories, but also one category can be used for multiple events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are basically transforming each DataRow into a Categories object and adding them to the event? You can achieve this sort of thing by using a Linq Select, (this is termed a projection).

To create a list of Categories ...

```
DataRow[] aDr = row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation");
var categoryList = aDr.Select(row => new Categories()
                              {
                                 category.CategoryID = Int64.Parse(dr["category_id"].ToString());
                              });

// add them to your event
events.CategoryList.AddRange(categoryList);

// or ...
events.CategoryList = categoryList.ToList();
```

The last step, where you add your categories to the event depends on the type of your CategoryList, whether it has an AddRange method, or whether you can set it to a new collection or list of categories.

You can then combine the outer for-each as follows:

```
var eventsList = eventsTable.AsEnumerable().Select(eventRow => new Events()
  {
     Description = eventRow["event_description"].ToString(),
     CategoryList = eventRow.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
                            .Select(row => new Categories()
                              {
                                 category.CategoryID = Int64.Parse(row["category_id"].ToString());
                              })
                            .ToList()
  }
```

Note this uses the following extension methods on DataTable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx

Comment: hi, this is a good answer. Is it also possible to eliminate "foreach (DataRow row in eventsTable.Rows)" convert it to a LINQ query and add your answer as a subquery to the new LINQ query.

Comment: Sure .... see my updated answer. Please up vote / mark as answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: hi coline, i don't have a .Select method under Rows

Comment: Is that similar to calling eventsTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select ?

Comment: Hi, I am just wondering where you get this. category.CategoryID = Int64.Parse(dr["category_id"].ToString());  Where is dr and "category."

Comment: last question. ToList() returns type IEnumerable could it possibly return a Generic.List type

Comment: Sure ... use Cast<MyType>().ToList()

Comment: What if the field "category_id" is 'NULL' from the database? This LINQ query would throw an exception. How would you handle for this?